# Spring Integration - Failing to Retrieve Oracle Array OUT PARAM

Tags: java, spring-integration

**Description**: Attempting to create a gateway service call that returns a oracle array type. Specially getting the sys.dbmsoutput_linesarray. The error I get below seems that I have something wrong on my configuration when I register the OUT param or possibly in the service. Wondering if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Error Message:**
CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call GET_DBMS_OUTPUT(?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111

Referenced Code Example I am trying to do in spring integration:
[JAVA DBMS ORACLE ARRAY CALLABLE STATEMENT EXAMPLE](https://github.com/raverkamp/oraclejdbc/blob/master/src/oraclejdbc/DbmsOutput.java)

Oracle 12c - PL SQL Function:

```
create or replace function get_dbms_output
    return dbmsoutput_linesarray
as
    l_output dbmsoutput_linesarray;
    l_linecount number;
begin
    dbms_output.enable;
        dbms_output.put_line('This is a line');
        dbms_output.put_line('This is another line');
        dbms_output.put_line('This is the last line.');


    dbms_output.get_lines(l_output, l_linecount);

    if l_output.count > l_linecount then
        -- Remove the final empty line above l_linecount
        l_output.trim;
    end if;

    return l_output;
end get_dbms_output;
```

Spring Context File - Taken from spring integration git hub example **stored-procedure-oracle** . Sample code was augmented with the following outbound gateway.

```
<bean id="sqlReturnArray" class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlReturnArray"></bean>

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
    id="outbound-gateway-function-dbms" request-channel="procedureDBMSRequestChannel"
    data-source="dataSource" 
    stored-procedure-name="get_dbms_output"
    expect-single-result="true">

    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="l_output" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).ARRAY}"  type-name="DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY" direction="OUT" return-type="sqlReturnArray" />

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

JAVA - Updated String Conversion Service

```
public interface StringConversionService {

    /**
     * Converts a String to Upper Case.
     *
     * @param stringToConvert The string to convert to upper case
     * @return The converted upper case string.
     */
    String convertToUpperCase(String stringToConvert);

    Integer getNumber();

    @Payload("new java.util.Date()")
    String[] getLines();
}
```

JAVA - MAIN

```
final StringConversionService service = context.getBean(StringConversionService.class);

        System.out.println("Calling Stored Proc");
        String[] dbmsLines = service.getLines();
```

Updated:
Spring Config:
- Added a bean for SqlReturnArray.
- Added a return-type for a reference to SqlReturnArray bean
- Change the StringConversionService to use a String[] instead of oracle Array return type.
- Updated main class to get String[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add [`return-type`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#sp-common-config-subelements) and implement it somehow like [`SqlReturnArray`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#d0e2456):

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="l_output" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).ARRAY}"  type-name="DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY" direction="OUT" return-type="sqlReturnArray" />
```

Where `sqlReturnArray` is a bean of that `SqlReturnArray`.

And of course, handle the result as a `String[]` already, not a unavailable there `ARRAY`.

Comment: Do you always have to use the return-type for OUT params? It seems in the examples it doesn't always use it. Is that because Spring uses the JDBC meta data under the covers to determine what is being returned ? Like varchar or number.

Comment: No, you have to use it for non-standard, complex types

Comment: Added spring-data-jdbc-core 1.2 . Now getting a spring context error now adding that above.

Cannot resolve reference to bean '#{new org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlReturnArray()}'... while setting argument;org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1003E:(pos 0): A problem occurred whilst attempting to construct an object of type 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlReturnArray' using arguments '()'

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my bad. That should be a bean reference. I've edited my answer

Comment: Still getting the same error as I had originally in my post. I update my original post with the edits we have talked about. You mentioned to handle the result as String[] . Should that be the return type on the service call? Or should that be something else like ARRAY?

Comment: Well, in your case it is `function `, not procedure. `is-function = true` is there for you

Comment: right. That did the trick. Once I added the is-function = true it worked. When I googled that error still made me think a issue the IN / OUT param types. Wow that was difficult but will be a good example for others who want the array. I will update the solution accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136091/discussion-between-haju-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: That looks like a problem with encoding. Sorry can't chat from iPhone

Comment: Possibly the dbmsoutput_linesarray type. I thought would return varchar2 array.  I will try converting it to a normal varchar2 array and seeing if that works.

Comment: Still haven't found away to return something other than a value of ??? in my array. Since I am using Oracle 12c, does spring support the new oracle extensions? In the documentation below it says I should use oracle.jdbc.OracleArray.
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC28906

Comment: You don't use `oracle.sql.ARRAY implements oracle.jdbc.OracleArray`. I'm pretty sure that problem is with different encoding in the `dbms_output` and what you expect in Java. Would be better to keep the same.