# Stored Procedure OutBound Gateway Return Type for Oracle Clobs?

Tags: spring-data, spring-integration

Attempting to adjust my solution in the following link to handle a CLOB OUT Param. What would the returnType be for handling oracle clobs be? I didn't see reference to it in documentation except for lob handling.

[Previous Question - Handling OUT Array Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324142/spring-integration-failing-to-retrieve-oracle-array-out-param)

```
<bean id="clobSqlReturnType" class=org.springframework.integration.jdbc.storedproc.?></bean>


<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
    id="outbound-gateway-function-dbms" request-channel="procedureDBMSRequestChannel"
    data-source="dataSource"
    is-function="true" 
    stored-procedure-name="get_dbms_output2"
    expect-single-result="true">
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="c1" type="CLOB"  type-name="" direction="OUT" return-type="clobSqlReturnType" />       
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution. You should do something yourself. Like this:

```
public class ClobSqlReturnType implements SqlReturnType {

    @Override
    public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
       Clob clob = cs.getClob(paramIndex);
       return clob != null ? clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length()) : null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought. I saw your gateway test procedure with the code sample using it and wasn't sure if it wasn't something that already existed ad a type.